# What is the easiest way to trigger an api endpoint on an hourly bases using azure?

Tags: azure

I have an App Service that runs FastApi in a Docker Container. I need to call a certain endpoint every hour.
What is the easiest way to achive this?
My plan so far is to setup the smallest VM available and run a cronjob.
Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some simpler options:

1. [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/overview) - run a powershell script on a schedule to call your API. All PaaS service, cost only for time running and a generous free amount so will likely cost very little, if anything
2. [Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http-swagger) - Run a workflow that makes a rest call. Again, PaaS service, and very little cost.

I would look at one of these, both will work.